# How to link code to the GUI with Cocoa-Applescript on Xcode

Tags: xcode, cocoa, user-interface, applescript, applescript-objc

I am trying to link my code to my GUI. But it won't let me.

Currently, I have a label, Button, and a Text Field on my GUI. This is my code for the GUI:

```
-- IBOutlets
property window : missing value

on buttonClicked_(sender)
    display alert "Hello there " & (stringValue() of textField)
end buttonClicked_

on applicationWillFinishLaunching_(aNotification)
    -- Insert code here to initialize your application before any files are opened 
end applicationWillFinishLaunching_

on applicationShouldTerminate_(sender)
    -- Insert code here to do any housekeeping before your application quits 
    return current application's NSTerminateNow
end applicationShouldTerminate_
```

When I try using the App Delegate tool, It doesn't work. I drag it to the parts on the GUI and it makes a blue line. But, The only thing the shows up under "Outlets" is "Window"

If I run the program, The GUI comes up, but it doesn't do anything cause the code isn't connected!

How do I connect my code to my GUI?

Extra Info: Xcode 5.1

Comment: James, I think you're using old documentation for "Applescript Studio Apps". That is no longer the way it works in Xcode 5.1. You need to use a resource that include Outlets and Bindings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to declare the outlet and then connect the outlets in the xib. ctrl-drag (or click right mouse button and drag) from AppDelegate to the textfield.
Then ctrl-drag from the button to the AppDelegate and choose the method, you want to send.

```
    -- IBOutlets
    property window : missing value
    property myTextField : missing value


    on applicationWillFinishLaunching_(aNotification)
    -- Insert code here to initialize your application before any files are opened 
    end applicationWillFinishLaunching_

    on buttonClicked_(sender)
        display alert "Hello there " & myTextField's stringValue
    end buttonClicked_

    on applicationShouldTerminate_(sender)
    -- Insert code here to do any housekeeping before your application quits 
    return current application's NSTerminateNow
    end applicationShouldTerminate_
```